# javascript - get the date of next day in week?

Tags: javascript

how do I get, for example, the date of next monday and the time 5:30PM, and calculate the difference between current date and time and that date and time?

if I run it now at 8/28/2020 17:35, it should give me 8/31/2020 17:30 and the difference 2 days 23 hours 55 minutes.

Comment: Next day in the week would be Saturday. Do you want the next business day, maybe? Or, maybe you input the day of week like Monday and the function returns the date and difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this help:

```js
// takes dayIndex from Sunday(0) to Saturday(6)
const getNextDay = (dayIndex) => {
  const today = new Date();

  today.setDate(
    today.getDate() + ((dayIndex - 1 - today.getDay() + 7) % 7) + 1
  );
  today.setHours(17, 30, 00);

  return today;
};

const getTimeleft = (dateNow, dateFuture) => {
  let seconds = Math.floor((dateFuture - dateNow) / 1000);
  let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
  let hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  let days = Math.floor(hours / 24);

  hours = hours - days * 24;
  minutes = minutes - days * 24 * 60 - hours * 60;
  seconds = seconds - days * 24 * 60 * 60 - hours * 60 * 60 - minutes * 60;

  return `${days} days ${hours} hours ${minutes} minutes`;
};

const now = new Date();
const nextMonday = getNextDay(1);
const timeleft = getTimeleft(now, nextMonday);

console.log(nextMonday.toLocaleString());
console.log(timeleft);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use moment.js, it's a very useful library when it comes to dates:

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script>
const today = moment();
const nextMonday  = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(1);
nextMonday.set({'hour': 17, 'minute': 30, 'seconds': 0});

console.log(nextMonday.toString());

const duration = moment.duration(nextMonday.diff(today));
const days = duration.asDays();
const hours = (days - Math.floor(days)) * 24;
const minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60;

console.log("days", Math.floor(days));
console.log("hours", Math.floor(hours));
console.log("minutes", Math.floor(minutes));
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working example:**

```js
function nextWeekMonday(date)
  {
    var diff = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + (date.getDay() === 0 ? -6 : 1);
    var currWeekMonday = new Date(date.setDate(diff)); 
    return new Date(currWeekMonday.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  }
 
 function getDateDifference(current, future) {
  // get total seconds between the times
  var delta = Math.abs(future - current) / 1000;

  // calculate (and subtract) whole days
  var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
  delta -= days * 86400;

  // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
  var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
  delta -= hours * 3600;

  // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
  var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
  delta -= minutes * 60;

  // what's left is seconds
  var seconds = delta % 60;
  
  return `${days} Days, ${hours} Hours, ${minutes} Minutes, ${seconds} Seconds`;
 }

var curr = new Date; // get current date
var nextMonday = nextWeekMonday(curr);

console.log(getDateDifference(curr, nextMonday));
```